# not calling a table parameter in rails sql database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, nomethoderror

[image]I'm a new ruby developer and cant find the error  both the database has the table but it is not calling

```
<% @orders.each do |order| %>


    <tr>

        <td><%= order.listing.name %></td>
        <td><%= order.buyer.name %></td>
        <td><%= order.created_at.strftime("%B %-d, %Y") %></td>

    </tr>
    <% end %>
</table>
```

and the database has a value added to the orders and listings-name.

Total GitHub repo is https://github.com/dinesh124/roughmart?files=1
The error is nomethod error  order.listing.name cannot find name - in sales page after sign up

Comment: For what field you're getting the blank value? What is `@orders`? Are you sure, that you really have values for order.listing and order.buyer?

Comment: I'm getting a nomethod error and I'm following a tutorial of baserails etsydemo ,i think @orders is a function like listings.any help would be really appreciated....and yes they do have values

Comment: Please, add corresponding controller action (looks like it is index) and a full error message to the question (use `Edit` button)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have incorrect association between Order and Listing. Look at your `schema.rb` - there is `t.string "listing_id"` in orders table, but it should be integer. Change column type in migration

```
def up
  change_column :orders, :listing_id, :integer
end

def down
  change_column :orders, :listing_id, :text
end
```

You need to use up and down methods since `change_column` is irreversible

Comment: still getting undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass this error ,i rollbacked and again migrated with newchanges

Comment: Are you sure that all order have listing_id set?